# Unable to extract DIC

Tags: r, jags, runjags

I am using runjags and am trying to get the DIC for my model.

I know that if I print the runjags object it will return the model summary which would include the DIC, but my model a lot of variables, so calculating the summary statistics is taking a long time.  When I use `summarise=FALSE` the DIC is not returned.

I have tried using: `extract(runJagsObj, what='dic')`

But it returns this error message:
`"Error: Please supply column name"`

Is there a way to either see the DIC in the summary information without having to calculate the summary statistics for every variable?  Or why is extract not working?

I'm using `method=parallel` if that is helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out the `"Error: Please supply column name"` error.

I was using ggmcmc for plotting which requires tidyr.  Tidyr has a naming overlap with `extract`.  I was able to resolve the naming conflict by loading runjags after ggmcmc which resolved the error.

Comment: Good catch. The same thing happens with rstan. I'll probably get in the habit of prefixing it with the namespace, e.g., rstan:::extract.